# How can I find where was my thread interrupted?

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans

I probably changed something in my project unintentionally. Now a key thread gets interrupted when it's not supposed to and `isInterrupted` returns true when the thread should be running.

Because nobody will find the problem for me, I'm asking for help on ways to find it. I need to find:

- at best, the location where thread was actually interrupted and output it in console when the program is running
- or all places where it is being interrupted in the code and comment them out one by one

Because IDE tools and debugger may play a role in my search I will add that I'm using NetBeans IDE.

Comment: `Thread.interrupt()` is public - you could override it and take a stack trace.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon To be curmudgeonly, the fact that it's public is irrelevant. What matters is that it isn't final.

Comment: @EJP - You are correct as always.

Comment: NetBeans: Go to the "Navigate" menu -> Go to Type -> java.lang.Thread -> right-click on the interrupt method -> select "Find Usages".  Repeat for java.util.concurrent.Future.cancel(true).

Comment: You can breakpoint the `Thread.interrupt()` method and see where it is called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could run it under a special thread that logs the stack when it is interrupted:

```
// A simple process.
class Process implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
    }

}

public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Process()) {
        @Override
        public void interrupt() {
            // Log a stack trace when iterrupted.
            new Exception("Where the hell did that come from!").printStackTrace(System.out);
            // Pass it up the chain.
            super.interrupt();
        }
    };
    t.start();
    Thread.sleep(2048);
    t.interrupt();
    t.join();
}
```